# PHP: Fetching events from database to fullcalendar based on dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

I am trying to filter the events on a calendar (Full Calendar plugin) using a dropdown select. The data is getting fetched, however it doesn't seem to display in the calendar present on my page.

I am attaching the code below:

**Dropdown**

```
        $categories = get_terms( 'eventcat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0', 'parent=0' );
        <select id="ccategory" style="padding:5px;background:#f0f0f0">
            <option value="0">Select Category</option>
            <?php if(!empty($categories)) { foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>
            <?php } } ?>
        </select>
```

**Calendar Div**

```
<div id='calendar1' style='display:none;'></div>
```

**PHP Query: from an external file**

```
$catid = $_POST['id'];
$userid = $_POST['user'];
$sql = 'SELECT p.post_title, p.ID, t.term_id, gce.start_date, gce.end_date FROM gc_posts p LEFT JOIN gc_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID LEFT JOIN gc_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id LEFT JOIN gc_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id LEFT JOIN gc_calendar_events gce ON p.ID = gce.event_id WHERE t.term_id = '.$catid.' AND gce.user_id = '.$userid.'';
$values = '';
    foreach($result as $v) { 
        $title = get_the_title($v['ID']);
        $url = get_permalink($v['ID']);
        $values = array('title' => html_entity_decode($title), 'start' => $v['start_date'], 'end' => $v['end_date'], 'url' => stripslashes($url), 'color' => '#33cc33');
    }
echo json_encode($values);
```

**Jquery function**

```
<script>
    function getEvents(){
        alert("hi");
       var id = $('#ccategory').val();
        alert(id);
       var user = $('#current_user').val();  
       alert(user);             
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.0.113/goacal/get_calcat_calendar.php",
        data: {id: id, user: user},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data ) {
            var events="";
              $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
                  events=events+""+key + ": '" + value+"',";

                      });
            alert(events);
           $("#calendar").css("display", "none"); 
           $("#calendar1").css("display", "block"); 

         $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
                 events: [
                    events
                     ] 
         });        
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

**Function call when the dropdown has been selected**

```
<script>
   $('#ccategory').change(function(){

        getEvents();

    });     
</script>
```

So the `alert(events)` is fetching the correct data, but when the function is done running the calendar is blank. The display none and display block is to hide the previous calendar which is working fine. I have been struggling with this for the past 1 day. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any other details are required for further reference.

**EDIT:**

I have changed my function using the callback but it still does not display the events on the calendar.

Attaching the new script below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.0.113/goacal/get_calcat_calendar.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                start: start.unix(),
                end: end.unix(),
                id: 109,
                user: 1
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                console.log(doc);
                var events = [];
                //alert(doc.title);
                $.each(doc, function(key,value) {
                console.log(key + ": " + value);
                    events.push({
                        key: value,
                    });
                });

                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello here is the problem. correct this section of your code. 
make sure you create an object for the events variable.

```
var events = "{ .... }"
```

here is example

```
success: function( data ) {
            var events="{";
              $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
                  events=events+""+key + ": '" + value+"',";

                      });
             events +="}";
            alert(events);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It still isn't fetching the data onto the calendar.

Comment: send me what is return in the alert(events) function

Comment: `{title: 'Balikali ॐ – Techno & Goa',start: '2017-11-25',end: '2017-11-28',url: 'http://192.168.0.113/goacal/event/la-beach-picnic/',color: '#33cc33',}`

Comment: remove the last comma( ,) after color

Comment: It's a loop, is there anyway to do so?

Comment: use events.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '')  make sure to call the replace function before the events += "}"

Comment: Hi, it removed the last comma, But still no output

Comment: `{title: 'Balikali ॐ – Techno & Goa',start: '2017-11-25',end: '2017-11-28',url: 'http://192.168.0.113/goacal/event/la-beach-picnic/',color: '#33cc33',{title: 'Balikali ॐ – Techno & Goa',start: '2017-11-25',end: '2017-11-28',url: 'http://192.168.0.113/goacal/event/la-beach-picnic/',color: '#33cc33'}`

Comment: it should work. checkout this character" Balikali ॐ – Techno & Goa" the funny chinese character may not be support by calender display

Comment: But it is returning 2 and the first isn't closing correctly. In normal PHP while fetching it in an array, it is working with the character.

Comment: try it without the character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159866/discussion-between-eddysoft-and-david-noronha).